# Get user name (from the chatbot) when integrated to Facebook messenger

Tags: botframework

I'm building a chatbot which I'll later deploy to azure and integrated to Facebook messenger, I made use of the micosoft bot framework sample which is the welcome user sample in github https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/03.welcome-user

When I run the sample in visual studio and test it in the bot emulator, the welcome message will display something "Welcome - user". I would like to get the username of the user the bot will be chatting with when integrated to facebook messenger, for example "Welcome Peter", how do I do this please, though I'm yet deploy it and integrate to facebook messenger, will the sample get the username automatically?, Please help